# Importing MS Access 2007 table to SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access

Greetings, 
I want to import MS Access 2007 table to SQL 2005. I followed this link: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/importing/Import_Access_DB.asp
I did everything the same but I get the following error when doing final step:

```
    Could not connect source component.

Error 0xc0202009: Source - TestTable[1]: An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.


Error 0xc02020e8: Source - TestTable[1]: Opening a rowset for "`TestTable`" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

can someone please help me with this? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried working from the other end, that is, use Jet connection?

Comment: You might also like to post some simplified SQL.

Comment: I resolved the problem. Inside wizard described in the link above, I had to write my own query like :" SELECT * FROM TestTable" - originally when automatically generated it was "SELECT * FROM 'TestTable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5abe098d-c7e1-46c6-994a-09a2856eef0b&displaylang=en)?:

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access v4.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5abe098d-c7e1-46c6-994a-09a2856eef0b&displaylang=en)

[SQL Server Migration Assistant 2005 for Access V4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4ECD1E67-C64E-49E6-821E-C4D83D9D5FED&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)

> Microsoft SQL Server Migration
>   Assistant (SSMA) for Access is a tool
>   for migrating databases from Microsoft
>   Access to SQL Server 2005, SQL Server
>   2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2. SSMA 2008
>   for Access also supports migrating to
>   SQL Azure.

Comment: because I don't have licence and I can't register.

Comment: The migration assistant doen't require a license...

Comment: and the downvote is because.....?